# UIImage from NSDocumentDirectory leaking memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiimage

I currently have this code:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png", [postsArrayID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
```

It's loading in an image to set in a `UITableViewCell`. This obviously leaks a lot of memory (I do release it, two lines down after setting the cells image to be that image), and I'm not sure if it caches the image at all.

Is there another way, that doesen't leak so much, I can use to load in images multiple times, like in a tableView, from the Documents-directory of my app? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `leaks` tool or Instruments should tell you what exactly is leaking. However, the `image` and `imageView` properties retain their images, so you may need to ensure you're properly releasing them in the `dealloc` method for the UITableViewCell. But like AngeDeLaMort said, we really need more information to give you a precise answer.

Comment: Ah, that's right, I forgot to dealloc them in my UITableViewCell. Thanks.

And for record, Leaks only say that "UIImage at this line is leaking."

Comment: Stupid "This comment may no longer be edited"... Ofcourse, I meant to say *release*, not *dealloc*.

Comment: The images are still leaking, even though I'm releasing both the image created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and the cellImage in my custom cell in the dealloc method. Got any idea why?

Comment: Instrument's Leaks tool should be able to give you a nice stack view of the leak when you run the simulator. Otherwise I can't think of anything else in the code you posted that would cause a leak. Perhaps more context will help.

Answer (score 0):

What is leaking exactly?
If you alloc an image and release it after, I don't see the leak your are talking about? Maybe more code or more precision would help.

Comment: That line, that image, is leaking, according to Leaks. I think it was because I forgot to release the image in my custom UITableViewCell's .m file. Something's still leaking, but I think I'll be able to fix it now ;)